# Mondial Database: Select all countries where all cities start with "A"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to get every country out of Mondial database that has only cities that start with "A".

I already have the amount of cities each country has and the amount of cities each country has that start with an "A". My idea was to just compare the numbers of the count statement but I don't know how to compare 2 queries that are grouped.
The following tables are interesting for that task if you don't know about mondial.

City: Name, Country, Province, Population

Country: Name, Code, Capital, Area, Population

My queries were the following:

```
SELECT Country.Code, Count(City.Name)
FROM City,
     Country
WHERE Country.Code = City.Country
  AND City.Name LIKE 'A%'
GROUP BY Country.Name
```

And the query without `LIKE = 'A%'`

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hint: `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Or `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: How would that look like? I always get the error that I try to compare a table with the count value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @jarlh I would use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT Country.Code
FROM Country
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM City
  WHERE Country.Code = City.Country
    AND City.Name NOT LIKE 'A%'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it's a better approach to exclude all other cities than to compare the numbers of the one statement with the other?
And how would it look like with having?

Comment: @MeteorMesh with having you need to use conditional aggregation, I believe that in many cases `NOT EXISTS` is better